# Power consumption of virtual machines in Cloudsim

Tags: java, cloudsim

Can we add a powerModel for virtual machine also as we do it for host in Cloudsim (simulation Tool)? So that we can track the power consumption of each virtual machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [CloudSim Plus](http://cloudsimplus.org) you can compute the CPU usage and power consumption of a VM using the following code into your example:

```
private void printVmsCpuUtilizationAndPowerConsumption() {
    for (Vm vm : vmList) {
        System.out.println("Vm " + vm.getId() + " at Host " + vm.getHost().getId() + " CPU Usage and Power Consumption");
        double vmPower; //watt-sec
        double utilizationHistoryTimeInterval, prevTime = 0;
        final UtilizationHistory history = vm.getUtilizationHistory();
        for (final double time : history.getHistory().keySet()) {
            utilizationHistoryTimeInterval = time - prevTime;
            vmPower = history.powerConsumption(time);
            final double wattsPerInterval = vmPower*utilizationHistoryTimeInterval;
            System.out.printf(
                "\tTime %8.1f | Host CPU Usage: %6.1f%% | Power Consumption: %8.0f Watt-Sec * %6.0f Secs = %10.2f Watt-Sec\n",
                time, history.vmCpuUsageFromHostCapacity(time) *100, vmPower, utilizationHistoryTimeInterval, wattsPerInterval);
            prevTime = time;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

You don't implement specific PowerModel for VMs. The VM power consumption is determined by its CPU utilization and the Host's PowerModel.

You can get the complete example [here](https://github.com/manoelcampos/cloudsim-plus/blob/master/cloudsim-plus-examples/src/main/java/org/cloudsimplus/examples/power/PowerExample.java).

Comment: Thank you for this code. I was literally frustrated and was not able to calculate the power consumption. Can you also please suggest a solution of how to get the history of RAM Utilization and Bandwidth Utilization. It would be a great help.